# how to select a particular row in a data grid using selenium?

Tags: selenium

1.I have User Registration page and need to select newly registered user in a data table as admin.
2.based on the user roles it will be placed anywhere in the data grid.
3.Need to select a particular user for approve it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: No clue how to help you here.. Very vague question. Put in the HTML code, screen shots etc and define what part you need helpt with.

Comment: Could you give us more informations !!! we can not help you !

Answer (score 1):

Complete shot in the dark due to ack of information but assuming your table has a cell with the user name and you want to click on the row containing it:

selenium.click("//table[@id='']/descendant::tr[td[.='']]");

We would need to see the entire HTML of your page and we would need to know what information you are storing about the user you are registering to give you a accurate answer.

Comment: Simple, There is a table i need to find and select a particular row.

Comment: the above will do it, you just need to fill in the gaps:  selenium.click("//table[@id='<myTableIDHere>']/descendant::tr[td[.='<someTextInACellInTheRowIWantHere>']]");

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my solution for future readers:

If you have the row object, try to get it's columns collection.

Then click column 0.